# RegEx Match Speak Tags with Variable Attributes

Tags: php, regex

How would I return an array of all speak tag?
Example 1 and 2 work for their respective tags but I need to the RegEx to work on both and possibly more variations.

### Example 1

```
\preg_match_all(
    '#<speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">(.+?)</speak>#',
    $ssml, $speakChunks
);
```

### Example 2

```
  \preg_match_all(
      '#<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">(.+?)</speak>#',
      $ssml, $speakChunks
  );
```

### Sample SSML

> ```
> <speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
>     <voice name="en-US-AriaNeural">
>         <mstts:express-as style="cheerful">
>             That'd be just amazing!
>         </mstts:express-as>
>     </voice>
> </speak>
>
> <speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
> <voice name="en-US-GuyNeural">
>   <prosody rate="0.00%">Isn't it?</prosody>
> </voice>
> </speak>
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely can't use XPath, use `~<speak[^>]*>(.+?)</speak>~gs`.

Comment: Thanks! `'#<speak[^>]*>(.+?)</speak>#'` got the job done.